# Generate Sequence number per a set of 2 in a group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement where we need to generate Sequence number per a group in the set's of 2.

For example in the screenshot below, we have Workcenter repeated multiple times for a material and we need to generate a sequence number in the set's of 2.

- So if the workcenter is same in the operation 1 & 2(MONS003) then the
  seq number should be '1'.
- If the workcenter is same in the operation
  3 & 4(MONS003) then the seq number should be '2'.

We need to flag the sequence number per set of 2.

In this example as the Seq 1 & 2(MONS003) have become a set even though the workcenter is same for the operation 2 & 3 (MONSO003) it needs to move onto next set which is 3 & 4 (MONS003).

So each set of 2 needs to flagged with new sequence number if they are in a sequence.

Is it possible to generate something like in the Output column of the screenshot.
[image: Screenshot]

```
MATERIAL|NEW_OPR_SEQ|WORKCENTER|OUTPUT_FLAG
070147|1|MONSO003  |1
070147|2|MONSO003  |1
070147|3|MONSO003  |2
070147|4|MONSO003  |2
070147|5|MONSO003  |0
070147|6|MONGR025  |0
070147|7|VERSA008  |0
070147|8|LAGER     |0
912001|1|MONGR025  |0
912001|2|VERSA008  |1
912001|2|VERSA008  |1
```

Comment: I am sorry Navin, but I have read your question multiple times and I still don't understand what you are asking. Perhaps it would help if you included what the input data is.

Comment: He wants to generate sequence number for sets of two, instead of sequential. Eg., 1 &2, should have sequence number as 1, 3&4 should have sequence number as 2, 5&6 should have sequence number as 3 and so on.

Comment: @navin, can you please provide input data ?

Comment: Do you are running which version of SQL Server?  Your sequence always starts in one? And if the operation doesn't match with the provisions you set to 0?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basic Solution using [DENSE_RANK Window Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/dense-rank-transact-sql):

```
CREATE TABLE #Data( ID INT IDENTITY, MATERIAL VARCHAR( 10 ), NEW_OPR_SEQ INT, WORKCENTER VARCHAR( 20 ))
INSERT INTO #Data 
VALUES
( '070147', 1, 'MONSO003' ), ( '070147', 2, 'MONSO003' ), ( '070147', 3, 'MONSO003' ), ( '070147', 4, 'MONSO003' ),
( '070147', 5, 'MONSO003' ), ( '070147', 6, 'MONGR025' ), ( '070147', 7, 'VERSA008' ), ( '070147', 8, 'LAGER' ),
( '912001', 1, 'MONGR025' ), ( '912001', 2, 'VERSA008' ), ( '912001', 3, 'VERSA008' )

SELECT *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY MATERIAL, WORKCENTER, NEW_OPR_SEQ % 2 ORDER BY NEW_OPR_SEQ ) AS GroupNumber
    FROM #Data
```

Output:

```
ID          MATERIAL   NEW_OPR_SEQ WORKCENTER           GroupNumber
----------- ---------- ----------- -------------------- --------------------
1           070147     1           MONSO003             1
2           070147     2           MONSO003             1
3           070147     3           MONSO003             2
4           070147     4           MONSO003             2
5           070147     5           MONSO003             3
6           070147     6           MONGR025             1
7           070147     7           VERSA008             1
8           070147     8           LAGER                1
9           912001     1           MONGR025             1
10          912001     2           VERSA008             1
11          912001     3           VERSA008             1
```

**Explanation:**

`DENSE_RANK()` - window functions work like an inline `GROUP BY` statement; the above code splits (see `PARTITION BY` part) your rows into groups by 'MATERIAL' and 'WORKCENTER' and 'NEW_OPR_SEQ % 2'. Records in each group are numbered 1 to n using the order (see `ORDER BY`) provided by 'NEW_OPR_SEQ' column

`NEW_OPR_SEQ % 2` - is the trick that allows the whole thing to work. This code returns the remainder of the integer division by 2 i.e. 0 for even numbers and 1 for odd numbers. In essence this code splits your rows into even numbered ones and odd numbered ones.

If you want to return a 0 where a record does not have a matching record then you can use `COUNT()` function as follows:

```
SELECT *,
    CASE WHEN COUNT(*) OVER( PARTITION BY MATERIAL, WORKCENTER, GroupNumber ) = 1 THEN 0
        ELSE GroupNumber
    END AS GroupNumberOrZero
FROM (
    SELECT *,
        DENSE_RANK() OVER( PARTITION BY MATERIAL, WORKCENTER, NEW_OPR_SEQ % 2 ORDER BY NEW_OPR_SEQ ) AS GroupNumber
    FROM #Data ) AS Ranked
ORDER BY ID
```

Output:

```
ID          MATERIAL   NEW_OPR_SEQ WORKCENTER           GroupNumber          GroupNumberOrZero
----------- ---------- ----------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
1           070147     1           MONSO003             1                    1
2           070147     2           MONSO003             1                    1
3           070147     3           MONSO003             2                    2
4           070147     4           MONSO003             2                    2
5           070147     5           MONSO003             3                    0
6           070147     6           MONGR025             1                    0
7           070147     7           VERSA008             1                    0
8           070147     8           LAGER                1                    0
9           912001     1           MONGR025             1                    0
10          912001     2           VERSA008             1                    1
11          912001     3           VERSA008             1                    1
```

Comment: This was the perfect solution i was looking for. Thank you Alex.